# 3D plot with numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

So I'm trying to create a 3D plot and the code I wrote is:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
a=[1,5,10]
x=list(range(1,10))
y=list(range(1,10))
z=list(range(1,10))
for i in np.arange(1,9,1):
    r1=a[2]*y[i]-a[1]*z[i]
    r2=a[0]*z[i]-a[2]*x[i]
    r3=a[1]*x[i]-a[0]*y[i]
    ax.plot(r1,r2,r3)
```

For this I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-95-dd97076f2b6e> in <module>()
    14     r2=a[0]*z[i]-a[2]*x[i]
    15     r3=a[1]*x[i]-a[0]*y[i]
---> 16     ax.plot(r1,r2,r3)

   1537         # Match length
   1538         if not cbook.iterable(zs):
-> 1539             zs = np.ones(len(xs)) * zs
   1540 
   1541         lines = Axes.plot(self, xs, ys, *args[argsi:], 
**kwargs)

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

It looks like something's wrong with the plot command, but I can't pinpoint it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of mistakes in the the code :

In my case I managed to run it with :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
a=[1,5,10]
x=np.array(range(1,10))
y=np.array(range(1,10))
z=np.array(range(1,10))


r1=a[2]*y-a[1]*z
r2=a[0]*z-a[2]*x
r3=a[1]*x-a[0]*y

ax.plot(r1,r2,r3)
plt.show()
```

I changed the import so that you actually import pyplot as plt (which you use in your original code in plt.figure() )

Then instead of using lists for x, y and z I used bumpy arrays which allow you to add and multiply them together as in :

```
r1=a[2]*y-a[1]*z
```

And finally i added plt.show() which is required in my IDE to actually display the plot, but it is possible that you might not need it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def crossprod(val):
    return [(a[2]-a[1])*val,(a[0]-a[2])*val,(a[1]-a[0])*val]

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
a=[1,0,0]
array=[]
for i in np.arange(-50,50):
    cr=crossprod(i)
    array.append(cr)
Array=np.vstack(array)
x=Array[:,[0]].ravel()
y=Array[:,[1]].ravel()
z=Array[:,[2]].ravel()
ax.plot(x,y,z, label='a=%s' %a)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```